# how to give multiple where condition using linq query in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I want to give multiple where condition while binding data in mvc using linq. I tried where condition same as sql query and other type also but didnt work and showing error i.e.

> The specified type member 'YearID' is not supported in LINQ to
>   Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation
>   properties are supported.

Here is my code which I tried latest,

```
 public ActionResult FilterImage(int yearID, int eventID, int branchID)
{
    var content = db.eventRegistration.Select(s => new
    {
        s.EventRegistrationID,
        s.Image,
        s.IsActive
    });

    List<EventRegistrationViewModel> contentModel = content
       .Select(item => new EventRegistrationViewModel() 
       {
            EventRegistrationID = item.EventRegistrationID,
            Image = item.Image,
            IsActive = item.IsActive
       })
       .Where(c => c.IsActive == true && c.YearID == yearID && c.BranchID == branchID)
       .Take(15).ToList();

    return View(contentModel);
}
```

this code is not working for multiple where condition.

I know and this question is almost asked previous time but then also that answer is didn't work for this solution.

Thank You.

Comment: Problem is not in multiple conditions. Problem is in the single condition which uses `YearID` property.

Comment: can you show the solution of this problem

Comment: You should show how property `YearID` is defined in your entity

Comment: sorry....I didnt understand....???

Comment: Also I see that question which you telling as a duplicate but there solution is not get my question solution.

Comment: show how property YearID is defined in your entity

Comment: It is really difficult to say whats wrong without seeing the entity definitions.

Comment: You need to add following line ->  .Where(c => c.IsActive == true || c.YearID == yearID || c.BranchID == branchID)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you are trying but the solution is in `content` list you must have select `YearID` and `BranchID` because in `where` you are using it.

I don't know you need all properties or not it's different discussion but as of now you can do like below

```
 public ActionResult FilterImage(int yearID, int eventID, int branchID)
{
    var content = db.eventRegistration.Select(s => new
    {
        s.EventRegistrationID,
        s.Image,
        s.IsActive,
        s.YearID,
        s.BranchID
    }).ToList();

    List<EventRegistrationViewModel> contentModel = content.Select(item => new EventRegistrationViewModel()
    {
        EventRegistrationID = item.EventRegistrationID,
        Image = item.Image,
        IsActive = item.IsActive
    }).Where(c => c.IsActive == true && c.YearID == yearID && c.BranchID == branchID).Take(15).ToList();

    return View(contentModel);
}
```

Comment: The same thing I have done and also describe in my question also and hence it showing error.

Comment: Ohh i think i got it i forgot to add `ToList()` in `content` please see updated answer

Comment: @Curiousdev that brings whole database table to the client without any filtering applied on database side

Comment: Oh yes i know @SergeyBerezovskiy that's why i have already mentioned what he is doing with this i'm totally not awared

Comment: @Curiousdev same code I have done see properly my question.

Comment: did you apply `.ToList()` at end of `content` ? in `Select(` extension method you must select all properties which you wants to use in `where` as i understand from dis side